# Pass onClick functions as parameters through a lot of components

Tags: reactjs, function, parameters, next.js, code-duplication

I have the following question. Suppouse that I have the following code:

```
function Page(){

  const onClick = () => {
    // Do some code
  }

  return (
    <Organism onClick={() => onClick()} />
  )  
}

function Organism({onClick}){

  return (
    <Molecule onClick={() => onClick()} />
  )  
}

function Molecule({onClick}){

  return (
    <Atom onClick={() => onClick()} />
  )  
}

function Atom({onClick}){

  return (
    <Atom onClick={() => onClick()} />
  )  
}
```

Atom, Molecule and Organism can be used in another pieces of code across the project. I find it very hard for debugging, but I can not find another way of building react components without duplicating code. Is it a good practice? Is there another alternative?

Thanks

Comment: React context maybe?

Comment: I use react context in another sections of the code but I find that tool overkill for passing function throws components